# How combine multiple visibility properties binding (fluent) in MvvmCross for iOS?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, xamarin.ios-binding

i want to combine these 2 properties:

```
set.Bind(myObject).For("Visibility").To(vm => vm.property1).WithConversion("Visibility");
set.Bind(myObject).For("Visibility").To(vm => vm.property2).WithConversion("Visibility");
```

I read something like this for Android

```
local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(And(property1, property2))"
```

But don't know how to translate to fluent, how can i do?

Comment: I would recommend to add one more property to your ViewModel which will represent the union state of "property1 & property2". Then your bindings will be much cleaner

Comment: That was my solution, but my team project is against that, don't want to use another property if the view can control that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do it:

```
set.Bind(textField)
   .For(t => t.Hidden)
   .To($"{nameof(FooViewModel.property1)} && {nameof(FooViewModel.property2)}");
```

and

```
set.Bind(textField)
   .For(t => t.Hidden)
   .ByCombining("And", vm => vm.property1, vm => vm.property2);
```

In the second example the register of `And` keyword is important.

Both options give the same result: `textField` will be hidden only if both `property1` and `property2` are equal `true`